# Something went wrong initializing the native ReactLocalization module. Please check your configuration: Did you run 'react-native link'?

Tags: ios, react-native, module, localization

[image]

I am trying to use the library react-native-localization in my ReactNative app for ios, when I try to run I get the following error:

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution to my own question.
Add to the "Podfile" this 2 lines:

```
pod ‘ReactNativeLocalization’,
     :path => “../node_modules/react-native-localization”
```

Here is my complete "PodFile" example.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Transit' do
  project 'Transit.xcodeproj'
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
#  use_frameworks!
 pod ‘Firebase/Core’
 pod ‘Firebase/Messaging’
 pod ‘ReactNativeLocalization’,
 :path => “../node_modules/react-native-localization”

end
$
```

Then execute the command

```
pod install
```

To install the necessary components.